# Field vs Custom type in ORCHARD CMS

Tags: orchardcms

when I create a Module in CMS what makes me use custom fields if I can create a new field (from administration area for example)?

Is there a difference in performance, or the way it's handles or what ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you call a custom field? Fields are stored as XML in the database, so they are slightly harder to query. Projections does it by maintaining index tables. Fields are also harder to re-use than parts: a field will be specific to a type whereas you'll be able to reuse parts on more than a type.